# How to change the namespace of Silverlight RIA Service -- Remove tempuri.org

Tags: silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am developing a Silverlight 4 application using RIA Services, and I have the RIA Services SP1 Beta tools.

It would appear, upon inspection in Fiddler, that my Domain Service is in the namespace `http://tempuri.org`.

I'd like to control the namespace. Is is possible to swap out `http://tempuri.org` for something more meaningful to my organization?

Comment: [How to eliminate tempuri.org from your service WSDL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/12/how-to-eliminate-tempuri-org-from-your-service-wsdl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for every last instance of the default namespace in my SOAP-enabled DomainServiceHost. I am still missing some, but here are the ones I've found. Oh, this code also limits the endpoint to https and blocks metadata generation.

```
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace mySite.Web.Models
{
    public class DomainServiceHostFactoryEx : DomainServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new DomainServiceHostEx(serviceType, baseAddresses.Where(x => x.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https")).ToArray());
        }
    }
    public class DomainServiceHostEx : DomainServiceHost
    {
        public DomainServiceHostEx(Type domainServiceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses) : base(domainServiceType, baseAddresses)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ContractDescription> currentContract in this.ImplementedContracts)
            {
                currentContract.Value.Namespace = "http://myWebSite.com/";
                foreach (OperationDescription currentDescription in currentContract.Value.Operations)
                {
                    currentDescription.DeclaringContract.Namespace = "http://myWebSite.com/";
                    foreach (OperationDescription innerCurrentDescription in currentDescription.DeclaringContract.Operations)
                    {
                        foreach (FaultDescription innerCurrentFaultDescription in innerCurrentDescription.Faults)
                        {
                            innerCurrentFaultDescription.Action.Replace("http://tempuri.org", "http://myWebSite.com/");
                        }
                        foreach (MessageDescription innerCurrentFaultDescription in innerCurrentDescription.Messages)
                        {
                            innerCurrentFaultDescription.Action.Replace("http://tempuri.org", "http://myWebSite.com/");
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (FaultDescription currentFaultDescription in currentDescription.Faults)
                    {
                        currentFaultDescription.Action.Replace("http://tempuri.org", "http://myWebSite.com/");
                    }
                    foreach (MessageDescription currentMessageDescription in currentDescription.Messages)
                    {
                        currentMessageDescription.Action.Replace("http://tempuri.org", "http://myWebSite.com/");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected override void AddDefaultBehaviors()
        {
            base.AddDefaultBehaviors();
            this.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>().HttpsGetEnabled = false;
            this.Description.Namespace = "http://myWebSite.com/";
        }
    }
}
```

And you have to create a .svc file in the root directory or in the Services folder with the service endpoint (i.e. /Services/mySite-Web-Models-myDomainService.svc) with the following code inside:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="mySite.Web.Models.myDomainService"
                Factory="mySite.Web.Models.DomainServiceHostFactoryEx" %>
```